# Twitterizer - Search API Example

Tags: c#, api, search, twitterizer

Can someone please write up a quick example code on how to search the public twitter timeline for a specific hashtag or keyword or mention using the Twitterizer framework.

Thanks

Comment: Check out [this post](http://www.twitterizer.net/528/finding-urls-hashtags-and-mentions-using-entities/)

Comment: Yea I saw that..but I a little confused what this statement does:

var StatusResult = TwitterStatus.Show(10506615291641857);

I think it's pulling entities based on that id, but I am unsure how to pull entities based on a hash tag, or text or mention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the search API to search for a specific word or phrase.

In Twitterizer, it would look like:

```
TwitterResponse<TwitterSearchResultCollection> result = TwitterSearch.Search("#hashtag");
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this now:

```
OAuthTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(consumerKey, consumerSecret, Request.QueryString["oauth_token"],Request.QueryString["oauth_verifier"]);

OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
            tokens.AccessToken = accessTokenResponse.Token;
            tokens.AccessTokenSecret = accessTokenResponse.TokenSecret;
            tokens.ConsumerKey = consumerKey;
            tokens.ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret;


            TwitterResponse<TwitterSearchResultCollection> tr = TwitterSearch.Search("your query");

        TwitterSearchResultCollection results= tr.ResponseObject;
        List<TwitterSearchResult> resultList= results.ToList();
```

I hope this can still help someone.

Comment: have you tried doing this with searchOptions? doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: If you create a new ASP.NET website or ASP.NET Web application, VS should know the Request class. Note: this is only for a code behind file for a webpage. You'll not be able to use the Request in a separate class. I hope this helps.